# Nextjs and reactjs package.json error when deployinh on vercel. Any suggestions on how I should approach this problem?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, package.json, vercel, sanity

Looks like I have a dependency compatibility problem or I have installed different versions of sanity/client. I have two package.json files. One is for frontend and other is for backend. Here's how they look: frontend

```
{
  "name": "realestate",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fontsource/inter": "^4.0.0",
    "@sanity/client": "^3.2.0",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.1",
    "next": "12.1.0",
    "next-sanity-image": "^3.2.1",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.12",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^13.3.0"
  }
}
```

and backend:

```
{
  "name": "realestate",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "package.json",
  "author": "RT",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "sanity start",
    "build": "sanity build"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "sanity"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@sanity/base": "^2.29.5",
    "@sanity/core": "^2.29.5",
    "@sanity/default-layout": "^2.29.5",
    "@sanity/default-login": "^2.29.5",
    "@sanity/desk-tool": "^2.29.5",
    "@sanity/eslint-config-studio": "^2.0.0",
    "@sanity/vision": "^2.29.5",
    "eslint": "^8.6.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7",
    "react": "^17.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: next-sanity-image@3.2.1
npm ERR! Found: @sanity/client@3.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@sanity/client
npm ERR!   @sanity/client@"^3.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @sanity/client@"^2.11.0" from next-sanity-image@3.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/next-sanity-image
npm ERR!   next-sanity-image@"^3.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @sanity/client@2.23.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@sanity/client
npm ERR!   peer @sanity/client@"^2.11.0" from next-sanity-image@3.2.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/next-sanity-image
npm ERR!     next-sanity-image@"^3.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-09-06T19_59_11_088Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-09-06T19_59_11_088Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1

I have tried changing @sanity/client versions, but it still throws me the same error. I am new to coding world. I have tried looking for dependency requirements in order for them to be compatible, but couldn't find anything usefull to solve my problem. Please let me know if you have any ideas on how to fix this issue.